# How to find common elements from a list of lists such that order of occurrence is maintained?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists where the length of the lists are same. I need to find the common elements from them with the order of occurrence maintained.
For example:

Suppose the list of lists is `[['a','e','d','c','f']['e','g','a','d','c']['c','a','h','e','j']]`
The output list should contain `['a','e','c']` Priority should be given to elements which occur earlier in most of the lists. In this example 'a' occurs earlier, then 'e' and so on.
How to proceed with this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you experiencing?

Comment: Break the problem into two parts: first figure out the common elements, then figure out a way to sort them that reflects your criteria (sounds like maybe you want to sum the indices of their appearances so as to get an average and use that as a sorting key).

Comment: I have tried ```reduce((lambda x,y: x & y), map(set, l))``` where ```l``` is the list of lists. But it does not maintain order.

Comment: You got the first part, now you just need to sort with the key you want.

Comment: Is the output `[a, e, c]` because this is the order for the first list, or because this pattern is reflected in most of the lists? you should also clarify that using perhaps a separate example.

Comment: something like: `sorted(set(x for a in l for x in a if all(x in a for a in l)), key=lambda x: sum(a.index(x) for a in l))`

Comment: @rv.kvetch I have mentioned that priority should be given to elements that occur earlier in most of the lists.

Comment: Yes but the example still leads one to infer that the solution is `[a, e, c]` because this is the pattern for the first list (which is ofc not the case). you should update the example to show that this is not the case.

Comment: The answer by @Samwise is the perfect comprehensive solution. The answer below gives the same result but has more lines of code.

Comment: I personally like the accepted answer as it's a bit easier to understand. @Samwise solution is also great, but I find it a bit hard to comprehend what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could find common items first then sorted it

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [['a','e','d','c','f'],['e','g','a','d','c'],['c','a','h','e','j']]

common = set(data[0])
for line in data:
    common = common.intersection(set(line))

res = defaultdict(int)
for line in data:
    for idx, item in enumerate(line):
        if item in common:
            res[item] += idx
[item[0] for item in sorted(res.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])]
```

output:

```
['a', 'e', 'c']
```

Comment: A similar result using a one liner is given above by @Samwise. I am accepting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution that I managed to get working:

```
data = [['a', 'e', 'd', 'c', 'f'],
    ['e', 'g', 'a', 'd', 'c'], ['c', 'a', 'h', 'e', 'j']]

# count number of times each character appears
char_count = {}
for arr in data:
    for char in arr:
        if not char in char_count:
            char_count.update({char: 1})
        else:
            char_count[char] += 1

# select characters that appear multiple times
common_chars = [i[0] for i in char_count.items() if i[1] > 1]

# remove characters that are not present in all lists
for char in common_chars:
    count = 0
    for arr in data:
        if char in arr:
            count += 1
    if count < len(data):
        common_chars.remove(char)

# final result with common characters
print(common_chars)
```

Resulting output:

```
['a', 'e', 'c']
```

Probably not the most efficient solution if you're working with lots of data though.